# $\lVert x_k \rVert \rightarrow \infty \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(x_k) \rightarrow+\infty$ implies existence of global minimiser

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function sucht that for every sequence $(x_k)_k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ holds
>
> $$\lVert x_k \rVert \rightarrow \infty \quad \Longrightarrow \quad f(x_k) \rightarrow+\infty.$$
>
> Show that at least one global minimiser exists.

I do not see how to prove this. The only thing I could think of would be to somehow use compactness, but I do not see how to apply that here. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Pick some $x_0$ and find some $M$ such that if $\|x\| >M$ then $f(x) \ge f(x_0)+1$. Then $\overline{B}(0,M)$ is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{argmin}[1]{\underset{#1}{\operatorname{arg min}}}$Consider a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $x_n\in\argmin{\lVert x\rVert\le n}{f(x)}$. Such a sequence exists because $f$ has a minimum on every closed bounded set.

Notice that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ must be bounded because $f(x_n)$ is decreasing (and therefore it cannot diverge to $\infty$). Therefore there is some $M\in\Bbb N$ such that $\lVert x_n\rVert\le M$ for all $n$, and thus $$\inf_{x\in\Bbb R^n}f(x)=\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}\min_{\lVert x\rVert\le n}f(x)=\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}f(x_n)\ge \inf_{\lVert x\rVert\le M} f(x)=f(x_M)$$